# In RestKit, what is the best way to RKRoute the GET of a list of objects as well as a single object?

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

Most RESTful APIs would route access to a resource, say Rabbit objects, like this:

```
GET  /rabbits                    <--- GET all rabbits. HTTP GET
GET  /rabbits/:rabbit_id         <--- GET one rabbit. Also HTTP GET
POST /rabbits
PUT  /rabbit/:rabbit_id
```

However, RestKit doesn't allow me to have two routes with the same HTTP verb, so this is impossible to add two GET routes to the RKObjectManager's RouteSet:

```
[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Rabbit class]
                                              pathPattern:@"rabbits"
                                                   method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

[manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[Rabbit class]
                                              pathPattern:@"rabbits/:rabbitID"
                                                   method:RKRequestMethodGET]];

//BOOM! Assertion failure
```

This causes an assertion failure: **"Cannot add a route with the same class and method as an existing route."**

Why can't I add a route with the same class and method? The **path** is different. How am I supposed to get both a list of Rabbits as well as a single Rabbit by ID? I know several workarounds, but I feel like this isn't something I should have to work around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use named routes you can do it. You can't use non-named routes because it generates an ambiguity into which one RestKit should use.

Comment: It seems like getObjectsAtPath: and getObject:path: should take care of that, though. I guess you could have a path like objects/:id refer to a collection of multiple objects, but that seems un-RESTful.

Answer (score 3):

The object class routes are designed to work with **instances**. The `GET` route in particular is used when you perform `getObject:someObject path:nil parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil`.

Collection loads are typically done via named routes or paths.

Comment: in case of post how can i use RKRoute

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone with the code, heres how to set up the route with name.

```
// When you are setting up your mapping, set up Route with Name.
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:LOGIN_URL
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithName:LOGIN_ROUTE pathPattern:LOGIN_URL method:RKRequestMethodGET]];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];


// And when you are ready to make the http call, do the following
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:LOGIN_ROUTE
                                                    object:userProfile
                                                parameters:params
                                                   success:success
                                                   failure:failure];
```